# app awaked (Active) by UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am prompting user with a `UILocalNotification`. When he launch my app from notification my app becomes active if it is in background. How can i know that the app was awaked (Active) from the notification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.

If your app was not running at all, then the app will be launched. When your `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called, the options dictionary will contain `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` (the value being the `UILocalNotification`). So the presense or lack of the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` can tell you if your app was launched via a response to the local notification or not.

If your app was already running when the notification was received, then the `-application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method will be called. Note, this will be called if your app is in the foreground or the background. So, check the `applicationState`: if the state is `UIApplicationStateActive` then the app is active and in the front; if `UIApplicationStateInactive` then the user tapped the action button to respond to the notification.

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases you have to handle..

1. **Application is not running**
    In a not running state, when application receives a notification application will be launched. In  ***application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*** you can check if the application is launched due to notification

   ```
   UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

   if (notification)
   {
     // application launched due to notification
   }
   ```
2. **Application running in the background**
    In this case you will get a call on ***application didReceiveLocalNotification:*** if your appDelegate implement this method

   ```
   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
   {

   }
   ```